# Is it possible to follow a link in a website that has specific text using Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, navigation

I'm trying to follow the first two links under "Certified Lists" on this site. 
https://dph.georgia.gov/wastewater-management

The date in the URL will change depending on when they add a new list.

So, I just want to be able to navigate to the two links based on their text "Septic Tank Installers" and "Septic Tank Pumpers".

I'm not trying to have anyone write code out for me.  I just can't find anything online that lets me know which module to use.

Any and all help is appreciated.

For example, i used this to navigate to this url

```
dls=https://www.sanantonio.gov/DevServ/CrystalReports/BldgActHDMonticelloPrk.xls'
resp = requests.get(dls)
```

Comment: I would recomend you try using regex

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using *[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)* library. If you have not installed it, you can do so using

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

or

```
python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Coming back to the question. You can use BeautifulSoup to get the `p` tag after the `h3` tag containing the text *"Certified Lists"* and then get the next two links after that.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
resp=requests.get('https://dph.georgia.gov/wastewater-management')
soup=BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'html.parser')
h3_next_p=soup.find('h3',text='Certified Lists').find_next('p')
for link in h3_next_p.find_all('a')[:2]:
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Output:

```
/sites/dph.georgia.gov/files/EnvHealth/Sewage/Contractors/EnvHealthInstallers2019-04-09.pdf
/sites/dph.georgia.gov/files/EnvHealth/Sewage/Contractors/EnvHealthPumpers2019-04-09.pdf
```

This will return the `href` as it is in the page source. Use the code below to get a link which you can use.

```
print('https://dph.georgia.gov/'+link.get('href'))
```